# Button onclick only works once

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have this html code for "Comentário" section:

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
 <button title="Editar" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" onclick="editar({{$feedback->id}})">
  <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
 </button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-10" id="esconde{{$feedback->id}}">
 <span class="textoInfo"><b>Comentário:</b></span>
 <br>
 {{$feedback->comentario}}
</div>

<div class="col-lg-10" id="mostra{{$feedback->id}}" style="display:none;">
 <span class="textoInfo"><b>Comentário:</b></span>
    <div class="input-group" id="showComent{{$feedback->id}}">
     {{ Form::text('comentario',$feedback->comentario, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' =>'textcoment'.$feedback->id]) }}
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="sendComent" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="submitComent({{$feedback->id}})"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>   </button>  
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

And this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function editar(id) {  
   $('#esconde'+id).hide();
   $('#mostra'+id).show();
 } 
</script>
```

The problem is that the the function onclick only works once. Is there a way to reload the #mostra div only? Or other simple way to do it. Thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to achive

Comment: PS (off-topic): In spanish (and derivates) the word "comentario" has no accent 

Comment: Well, I'm trying to replace a div from another. The toogle works fine for a simple div. I'm trying to use replaceWith() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but I assume you want to toggle one of the elements when someone presses the button. You have two options here really.

1. You can use the jQuery function [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle the element.
2. You can use .is(':visible') to see if the element is visible or not in a if statement and go from there.

Comment: Nice. But it works fine for one div. The code that i have replaces one div for another. The toogle show/hide the same element. But to replace one div for another?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to replace a div from another. The toogle works fine for a simple div. I'm trying to use replaceWith() function.

Answer (score 0):

It´s working. It was a matter of logic. I used show/hide functions. But I would keep toogle suggestion in mind.  Thanks :)